# How to implement promises in Firebase database in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a beginner in javascript and this is my first time asking a question here. I've been working on a Firebase project. I need to get a score from Firebase database, do some calculations on it, and save it back to Firebase database.

However these type of functions needs time. I've used setTimeout for debugging and testing purpose and it's working perfectly. However this isn't the right way to do it. I have to use promises. How to implement promises in my code?

```
setTimeout(async () => {
      var Ra;
      var Rb;
      let ref = firebase.database().ref("poeple");
      let query = ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo(firstName);
      const snapshot = await query.once("value")
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {
            var userData = userSnapshot.val();
            Ra = userData.score;
      });
    }

    let opponentQuery = ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo(hisOpponent);
    const snapshotTwo = await opponentQuery.once("value")
      if (snapshotTwo.exists()) {
        snapshotTwo.forEach((userSnapshot) => {
          var userData = userSnapshot.val();
          Rb = userData.score;
        });
      }
      var expectedA = 1 / (1 + Math.pow(10, (Rb - Ra) / 400));
      var expectedB = 1 / (1 + Math.pow(10, (Ra - Rb) / 400));
    
      var newRa = Ra + 32 * (1 - expectedA);
      var newRb = Rb + 32 * (0 - expectedB);

      var finalQuery = await ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo(firstName);
      finalQuery.once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.ref.update({score: newRa})
      });

      var opponentFinalQuery = await ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo(hisOpponent);
      opponentFinalQuery.once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.ref.update({score: newRb})
      });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You use promises throughout this code already--what specific issue are you having? How to wrap your entire operation in a promise?

Comment: Using setTimeout isn't right but if I remove it the code won't work

Comment: So you want to know how to return a final promise from this method so you can `await` it?

Comment: In such a way that when I remove setTimeout it will still work. I've spent time reading the documentations and i think I have to use .then and .catch but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

The reason it works in setTimeout() is because you've declared an async function. So that's what is needed to use async/await as you have here:

```
async function doWork() {
   const foo = await ...;

   return foo;
}

const foo = doWork();
```

You can skip the setTimeout call and just call the function directly.

Comment: If you noticed I haven't returned anything

Comment: I just wanna add .then and .catch to my code and I don't know how